# AlertDialog for icon selection as in Google Drive app

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-alertdialog

How to create an `AlertDialog` like this one in *Google Drive* app? I would like to have 9 icons instead of 20 colors, but for **the rest the result would be more or less the same**.

Note that in order to respect *MVC pattern* I would prefer to build the view in a xml file.

[image: AlertDialog example in Google Drive]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Color Picker Alert Dialog]
Well if you want to have an `alert dialog` like this,then save the code below in an .xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FAFAFA"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Select your color"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:shadowRadius="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:id="@+id/color1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/color2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/color3"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/color4"/>

</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">



</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button5"
        android:id="@+id/color5"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/color6"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/color7"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/color8"
        />
</LinearLayout>




    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="Done"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
```

Then from the java file make an alert dialog and set its content view to this .xml file.
After that make onClickListener for each of the button and do the task for each color picker.

as example if i want to set a method for button1 color picker.then

```
Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.color1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          appTheme.setThemeColor(Color.parseColor("#9CCC65")); //your own made method to change the color of the theme according to color picker
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I noticed you hard-linked sizes of images... how to properly define an adaptive behavior to the size of the screen?

Comment: It doesn't matter if i hard-linked the sizes of images,because i added this code in my androidMainfest.xm

    <supports-screens 
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

this code takes the screen size and shows the content according to that screen size

Comment: Ok, thanks :) that solved my problem

Comment: You are welcome.It's a good feeling to come at someones help :)